# Checksum or LastUpdatedTime for MemoryCache in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, memorycache

I have a custom centralized MemoryCache and wrapper to be exposed over network. The objects to be stored are expected to be large and accessed frequently. The network traffic might become a bottleneck just because of the size of the data.
So, I want to return some kind of value that the clients may ask first to check if they need a new value from the cache server. I have 3 options:

1. Generate checksum in the cache server and return to client while adding object to cache. 
   Generate
2. Get current time tick in the cache server and return to client while adding object to cache.
   In both the cases, the checksum or time tick will also be added in cache with  different key so that clients may query it separately.

I can avoid this if either of these values is available from MemoryCache directly. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.